# rangeOfMisspelledWordInString find random letters as valid word

Tags: ios

Can anybody duplicate this result?  I'm testing `rangeOfMisspelledWordInString` (in `iOS`) to find mispelled words and some random letters return a valid word as shown below.

```
UITextChecker* pSpellChecker = [[[UITextChecker alloc] init] autorelease];
NSRange rangeWord = NSMakeRange(0, 8);
NSRange rangeCheck = [_pSpellChecker rangeOfMisspelledWordInString:@"lhpcjeuw"
                                                             range:rangeWord
                                                        startingAt:0
                                                              wrap:NO
                                                          language:@"en_US"];
if (rangeCheck.location == NSNotFound) {
   NSLog(@"Valid Word:");
}
```

Below are some of the words that are also valid according to rangeOfMisspelledWordInString:
BTW, I've made sure to convert the following words to lowercase before testing.

```
LD
THY
THE
THECA
TD
HL
HT
YD
YLEQXXH
DV
DVX
DVXX
DVXXD
DVXXDX
DVXXX
DVHXG
DVHEJWCP
DH
DH
DPJLEHHY
```

Very strange.  Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think "the" and "thy" just might be valid words ;)

Other than that, my best guess is that the text system can't provide a guess for the word, and so ignores it entirely - the semantic meaning of "misspelled word" might not include "strings of letters which cannot conceivably be a misspelling of a word." I notice that when I type those strings into a system text field (e.g. in Messages), I don't get any replacement suggestions.

You could also make sure that your UITextChecker instance isn't set to ignore those particular words; take a look at the [`ignoredWords` property](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextChecker_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITextChecker/ignoredWords).

Comment: "thy" and "the" are actual words.  I threw those words in for sanity checks. I don't think the rest are real words though.  I'm trying to use the function to check for a correct spelling only and it seems that the current state of the API is not useable for that purpose.  If you type one of those non-words in Notes, there is no red wriggly underline.  In a Mail App, there is a red wriggly underline to indicate a misspelled word.

Comment: It's not in any way a bug.  But it's an incredible pity they don't include a call "is this a value word".  there are various products, packages etc around that do this, e.g. lexicontext.com

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I can reproduce it, and I would call this a bug. If I put in your test word, @"lhpcjeuw", it treats it as a valid word. But, if I use @"lahpcjeuw" (added an "a" in second position), it catches it. I noticed the same thing Tim did -- when writing this answer, the spell checker underlined that second one but not the first as I typed.

Comment: Right - it seems to be specifically finding "likely a misspelled word".  So, "Indina" is likely a misspelled word ("Indiana").  But "kkksjd" is not a mis-spelled word - it's just gobbledegook. (When you think about it, my typing "kkksjd" .. that really was not a "misspelled word" - it was just me typing gobbledegook)